# Does a dangling Linux boot entry interfere with the reinstallation of Linux dual-boot system?

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, boot-loader

My laptop contained a UEFI dual-boot system. I sent it out for hardware repairs and the dealer has reinstalled Windows 8 and, for good measure, wiped all Linux partitions (incidentally, without asking about the opportunity of it).

However, as I check the boot manager, I can still see the boot entry for Linux. It is obviously ineffective and the loader splashes into Windows. The current Windows also claims the whole hard disk space. Therefore, I intend to install the Linux operating system (Ubuntu) once again.

Hence the questions:

1. Say that I decide not to touch the boot manager. Is there a chance of conflict between the old and upcoming boot entries? Both will point to the Linux environment, at least nominally. I would not want to get stuck with obscurities in the Linux installation and bootstrapping just a few steps down the line.
2. Is it actually sensible to try and remove idle boot entries from the boot manager just to be safe? This better-safe-than-sorry scenario entails starting off from scratch also with the boot manager.

Thanks for thinking along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If your new Linux installation uses the same partition as the previous one, and the boot loader wasn't set up to pass the UUID of the file system to the kernel as a boot parameter, it might still work. Don't be surprised if it doesn't though.
2. When you install your new Linux system, the boot manager will re-scan the partitions and only add ones present; that is, it will remove the old Linux entry and add a new one.